# как написать функцию которая удаляет все пробелы кроме последнего?

Tags: python-3.x, строки

нужно написать функцию которая принимает строку и удаляет из нее все пробелы кроме последнего. я написал функцию, но она ничего не выводит и я не могу понять почему.
на выходе должно быть так 'Simple, remove the spaces from the string' ➞ 'Simple,removethespacesfromthe string'

```
def count_space(str_1:input('Введите строку:')):
    space = str_1.count(' ')
    rep_1 = str_1.replace(" ", "", space - 1)
    return rep_1
```

Comment: Она и не должна выводить, она возвращает строку без протокола труда, где её вызвали.

Comment: а можете подсказать как правильно написать?

Comment: @JunPy посмотри мой ответ. Так надо передавать значение в функция

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def probel(str_1):
    space = str_1.count(' ')
    rep_1 = str_1.replace(" ", "", space - 1)
    return  rep_1

str_1 = input('Введите строку:')
print(probel(str_1))
```

Вы должны передать строку в эту функцию, тогда будет выводиться так, как вы хотели

```
Введите строку:Simple, remove the spaces from the string
Simple,removethespacesfromthe string
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
space_count = str_1.count(" ")
str_2 = str_1.replace(" ", "", space_count-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы допустили небольшую ошибку в указании аргументов функции, дело в том, что запись `def count_space(str_1:input('Введите строку:')):` подразумевает следующее: функция `count_space` ожидает увидеть тип данных указанный через двоеточие, а там указан способ получения данных, поэтому ваша функция не обрабатывала строку должным образом, если вам принципиально сохранение данного вида аргументов, то можно использовать этот код:

```
def count_space(str_1: str):
    space = str_1.count(' ')
    rep_1 = str_1.replace(" ", "", space - 1)
    return rep_1


print(count_space(input('Введите строку:')))
```